# set the alarm manager to repeat every day but it repet all time after the hour i set

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alarmmanager

I'am trying to set the alarm manager for every day in single hour, I have followed android development tutorial;
it's work but if i pass the hour it keep broadcast;

assume i want it every day in 8 o'clock but if now its 9 o'clock and i will open the app it will trigger it again

```
calendar= Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, JobScheduler.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
            calendar.getTimeInMillis() , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent );
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, you want to repeat the alarm manager at a specific time every day?

Comment: yes,but it keeps repating,and i want just one time

Comment: the flag of pendingIntent should be one of the following: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#constants_2

Comment: actually i tried them all and they dont work